# Get currently logged in user asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net-2010

I´m having a bit of trouble and I would like to see if you all could help me out!

For my WebApp in ASP.net, I need to be able to get the user name.

I had been able to do it through:

user = Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name.ToString on my developement machine, but when i go to production, it shows ASP.net as user...

I also tried with

user = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString

and in dev station i get a blank string, and in production, I get "AppPool/ASP.net4.0

Any Ideas as to how i could get this working?

This WebApp is supposed to work in the Intranet.

Comment: Do you want the windows user identity of the client (the one visiting/using your intranet site) or of the process that is running the app pool?

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you've enabled Windows Authentication in your web.config (check your .config.xxx transforms too). You should see this tag in your web.config:

```
<system.web>  
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    ...
</system.web>
```